# Backbone events are firing multiple times after re-rendering sub-views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

We have a single Backbone view comprised of a sidebar and several sub-views. For simplicity, we've decided to have the sidebar and sub-views governed by a single `render` function. However, the `click .edit` event seems to be firing multiple times after clicking on one of the sidebar items. For example, if I start out on "general" and click `.edit`, then `hello` fires once. If I then click `.profile` on the sidebar and click `.edit` again, `hello` fires twice. Any ideas?

**View**

```
events: {
  "click .general": "general",
  "click .profile": "profile",
  "click .edit": "hello",
},

general: function() {
  app.router.navigate("/account/general", {trigger: true});
},

profile: function() {
  app.router.navigate("/account/profile", {trigger: true});
},

render: function(section) {
  $(this.el).html(getHTML("#account-template", {}));
  this.$("#sidebar").html(getHTML("#account-sidebar-template", {}));
  this.$("#sidebar div").removeClass("active");
  switch (this.options.section) {
    case "profile":
      this.$("#sidebar .profile").addClass("active");
      this.$("#content").html(getHTML("#account-profile-template"));
      break;
    default:
      this.$("#sidebar .general").addClass("active");
      this.$("#content").html(getHTML("#account-general-template"));
  }
},

hello: function() {
  console.log("Hello world.");
},
```

**Router**

```
account: function(section) {
  if (section) {
    var section = section.toLowerCase();
  }
  app.view = new AccountView({model: app.user, section: section});
},
```

**Solution**

My solution was to change the router to this:

```
account: function(section) {
  if (section) {
    var section = section.toLowerCase();
  }
  if (app.view) {
    app.view.undelegateEvents();
  }
  app.view = new AccountView({model: app.user, section: section});
},
```

This works for now, but will this create a memory leak?

Comment: If you post your router code, I can verify my hunch that you are creating duplicate view instances.

Comment: Okay, I posted the relevant section of the router.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem when I first started using backbone.  Like Peter says, the problem is that you have more than one instance of the View being created and listening for the event.  To solve this, I created this solution in my last backbone project:

```
/* Router view functions */
showContact:function () {
    require([
        'views/contact'
    ], $.proxy(function (ContactView) {
        this.setCurrentView(ContactView).render();
    }, this));
},
showBlog:function () {
    require([
        'views/blog'
    ], $.proxy(function (BlogView) {
        this.setCurrentView(BlogView).render();
    }, this));
},


/* Utility functions */
setCurrentView:function (view) {
    if (view != this._currentView) {
        if (this._currentView != null && this._currentView.remove != null) {
            this._currentView.remove();
        }
        this._currentView = new view();
    }
    return this._currentView;
}
```

As you can see, it's always removing the last view and creating a new one, which then renders.  I also add a require statement in the router because I don't want to have to load all views in the router until they are actually needed.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to see I'm not the only one dealing with this issue. This is a great solution.

Comment: @j-a-x Can you tell more about how you arranged Router and App files.

Comment: @jeevs sorry man, haven't touched backbone in a while.  I'm onto Angular now :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are attaching multiple view instances to the same DOM element and they are all responding to the events. Are you making a new view each time you navigate without removing the previous view?

Comment: You may be right, though I just tried `app.view.remove()` before creating the new view but then the new view doesn't render at all...

Comment: Well, you need to render it and attach it. Your `undelegateEvents` I _think_ will be OK, but I don't think it's the simplest backbone pattern that can work for your use case.

Comment: I'm definitely open to suggestions ;-)

Comment: I think the basic pattern for the router manipulating views should be construct, render, attach, remove, rinse, repeat. But Backbone is flexible, so do what you think is sound.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dynamic view, that renders different templates inside the same element (about 12), based on router params. Now, the container in which the view renders, is defined inside the view.render() like so "el: '#some-container'". Naturally, i have to remove the view if it exists, before creating a new or the same one, to prevent zombies and s#!t. Just as a reminder, calling view.remove(), actually removes '#some-container' from the DOM, meaning the view has no place to render in, except for the first time. Now, there are dozens of methods to prevent this from happening. Just thought i should share in case anyone needs to save a few hours of research.