# Backbone views events not working when rendering more than once

Tags: jquery, events, dom, backbone.js, parse-platform

I have an issue that I can't understand very well with Backbone views events. 
A few weeks ago, I ran into the "[multiple views events triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822518/backbone-events-are-firing-multiple-times-after-re-rendering-sub-views)" issue, because I was attaching all my views elements to an existing and never suppressed DOM element (`#page_content` in my page architecture, see below), and that I wasn't manually cleaning Views and Events).

As I didn't want to do the cleaning manually, **not by laziness** but because I find it error prone, I ended up with a fine workaround which is to never attach my views to existing DOM elements. So I only use `tagName` and `className` to create my views elements, which I then insert within an existing DOM elements (most often, within `#page_content`, see below). As Backbone removes events listeners if the DOM elements they are attached to are removed, and also garbage collects the Views if their element is removed from the DOM, I find this a very clean and easy way to handle Views and their events.

So... this has been working quite nicely until today. In one of my View, I am calling twice the `render` function. The first time the `render` function is called, everything works fine. Events are triggered and caught as expected. However if I call the `render` function a second time, none of my view events are fired anymore.

**Here is the template of my view :**

```
  <script type="text/template" id="chat_selection_template">
    <div class="push_me_down side_pad_me">
      <div id="schools_chat_container">
        <h2>Chat par école:</h2>
        <ul>
        <% if (schools) { %>
          <% for (var i=0; i<schools.length; i++) { %>
          <li class="school">
            <a href="/chat/school/<%= schools[i].id %>" class="mlb_text blue">
              <%=  schools[i].attributes.appellation_officielle_uai %>Rejoindre ce chat
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <% } %>
        <% } else { %>
          <li class="empty">Vous n'êtes assigné(e) à aucune école pour le moment. <a class="mlb_text blue" href="/select_lines">Sélectionner une école à laquelle emmener vos enfants en Pédibus</a>.</li>
        <% } %>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="lines_chat_container">
        <h2>Chat par ligne:</h2>
        <ul>
        <% if (lines) { %>
          <% for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) { %>
            <li class="line"><%=  lines[i].attributes.start_point_name %> - <%= lines[i].attributes.schoolName %> <a href="/chat/line/<%= lines[i].id %>" class="btn btn-mlb">Rejoindre ce chat</a></li>
          <% } %>
        <% } else { %>
          <li class="empty">Vous n'êtes inscrit(e) à aucune ligne pour le moment. <a class="mlb_text blue" href="/select_lines">Inscrire mon enfant à une ligne de Pédibus</a>.</li>
        <% } %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

**And here is the JS:**

```
      // Chat selection page View
  MLB.ChatSelectionView = Parse.View.extend({

    tagName:        'div',
    className:      'chat_selection_container',
    template:       _.template($("#chat_selection_template", MLB.TEMPLATES).html()),
    schools:        false,
    lines:          false,


    events : {
      "click #select_school_link":  "go_select_a_school", 
    },


    initialize : function() {
      var School        = Parse.Object.extend("School");
      var school_query  = new Parse.Query(School);
      var current_user  = Parse.User.current();
      var Line          = Parse.Object.extend("Route");
      var line_query    = new Parse.Query(Line);
      var self          = this;


      school_query.equalTo("parents", current_user);
      school_query.find().then(
        function(schools) {
          if (schools.length > 0) {
            self.schools = schools;
          }
          self.render();
        },
        function(error) {
          MLB.log_to_parse("middle",'chat_selection', 'Failed to retrieve schools.');
          self.render();
        }
      );


      line_query.equalTo("contributors", current_user);
      line_query.find().then(
        function(lines) {
          if (lines.length > 0) {
            self.lines = lines;
          }
          self.render();
        },
        function(error) {
          MLB.log_to_parse("middle",'chat_selection', 'Failed to retrieve lines.');
          self.render();
        }
      );
    },


    go_select_a_school: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Parse.history.navigate("consult_lines", {trigger: true});
    },


    render : function(schools) {
      this.$el.html( this.template({schools: this.schools, lines: this.lines}) ); 
      MLB.CONTENT.html(this.$el);
    },
  });
```

**And this is my app HTML architecture :**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="content-wrapper">

    <header id="page_header">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="logo">
          <a href="/" id="header_homepage">PetitBus</a>
        </h1>

        <div id="header_login"></div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="page_content"></div>


    <!-- TEMPLATES -->
    <div id="templates">
       [Backbone templates code]
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to understand why calling the `render` function a second time is screwing all up. To my limited understanding of what happens behind the seen, all DOM elements from the first render are removed when this happens, and so are their events listeners. But then the new DOM elements are inserted, and so are their events listeners... right? At least that is what I was expecting, but it seems that I am wrong.

Any insight of this is most welcome. I would like to deeply understand what is going on here before rushing in a wrong direction.

Many thanks

Comment: by calling render twice, do you mean the two calls you have in your code. One in callback of school_query and the other in callback of lines_query?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I do mean those two calls. 
I do it this way, so I can output something sooner to the user, and complete the view when the info from the second callback is back. 
Do you see anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `this.delegateEvents();` as the last line in your render function.

> Backbone documentation: "By default, delegateEvents is called within
>   the View's constructor for you, so if you have a simple events hash,
>   all of your DOM events will always already be connected, and you will
>   never have to call this function yourself."

So if you render your view a second time you need to call delegateEvents yourself as the constructor is not called again.

Comment: Roger that. I knew about `delegateEvents` but did not get very well what it was doing. With this case and your explanation, it is now crystal clear. Thanks!